# LINQ FirstOrDefault problem

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am stuck on a LINQ query.  Basically I have two tables linked by association on a uniqueID key.  One table contains things that look duplicated (tblDupes), another is the fact table (tblVouchers).  In the below query my 'sum' is working, but the FirstorDefault does not.  It returns an error 'cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'.

```
var dupeGroups = from d in db.tblDupes
                           group d by d.dupeGroup into g
                           select new 
                           { 
                               Group = g.Key, 
                               TotalVal = g.Sum(v => v.tblVoucher.TransactionAmtDecimal),
                               Vendor = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.tblVoucher.vendorName)
                            };
```

Any ideas?  I've tried many different permutations of FirstOrDefault, putting it at the end, etc etc.  I've also tried First().

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the parameter to FirstOrDefault is a predicate used for filtering. You want to select the field you want to retrieve first, and then grab the first result (methinks) like this:

```
var dupeGroups = from d in db.tblDupes
                 group d by d.dupeGroup into g
                 select new { 
                     Group = g.Key, 
                     TotalVal = g.Sum(v => v.tblVoucher.TransactionAmtDecimal),
                     Vendor = g.Select(x => x.tblVoucher.vendorName).FirstOrDefault()
                 };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is perfect!  Could have sworn I tried that.  Much appreciated.  I've been doing linq for a while and really hoped to have 'gotten' the detail of it some more by now :)

Comment: Not a problem :) Glad it helped you! Jon Skeet has a crazy 40-something part blog series about how he re-implemented LINQ to objects: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx Check it out if you dare... it might shed some light on some of the LINQ statements you might be fuzzy on.

Comment: Will do!  I do get the feeling that even though it has the appearance of being 'easy to use' you really need to understand the nuts and bolts of whats happening underneath to make full use of it.

Answer (score 4):

`FirstOrDefault` takes a predicate, meaning a `Func<T, bool>`.  However, you are passing, `x => x.tblVoucher.vendorName`, a `Func<T, string>`, since `vendorName` is a string.  The `bool` result is to indicate the first row that matches.  For example, to find the first row with a `vendorName` equal to "foo", you would pass in `x => x.tblVoucher.vendorName == "foo"`.